# Bootstrap - Image not covering inteire width of container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im starting a project using bootstrap and i've been having a little bit of trouble trying to figure out a way to make this image cover the inteire width of my container

any ideias??
appreciate the help!!!

here's my code
hey guys,

im starting a project using bootstrap and i've been having a little bit of trouble trying to figure out a way to make this image cover the inteire width of my container

any ideias??
appreciate the help!!!

here's my code

```css
:root {
    --DarkerGray: #1b1d1d;
    --Gray: #3F4545;
    --MediumGray: #464a4a;
    --DarkBlue: #123B79;
    --LightBlue: #18A5A7;
    --LightGray: #D9D9D9;
    --LighterGray: #eceaea;
    --White: white;
    --OrangeSelect: rgb(255, 166, 0);
}
html, body {
    user-select: none;
}
.navbar {
    background-color: var(--DarkBlue);
}

.nav-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 550;

}
.dropdown-item {
    cursor: pointer;

    font-weight: 550;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: var(--OrangeSelect);
}


#containerIMG {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>  
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      CARDÁPIO
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> PRATOS </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> LANCHES </a>   
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> SOPAS </a>     
                  </li>
                   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      BEBIDAS
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> ÁGUAS </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> SUCOS </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> REFRIGERANTES </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> CERVEJAS </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> VINHOS </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> APERITIVOS </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> DRINKS </a>    
                  </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white">RESERVAR MESA <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white"> PESQUISAR </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white"> MINHA CONTA </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white"> MEUS PEDIDOS</a>
              </li>
            </ul>   
          </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
        <img src="https://t.ctcdn.com.br/essK16aBUDd_65hp5umT3aMn_i8=/400x400/smart/filters:format(webp)/i606944.png" id="containerIMG">
      </div>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to delete the padding of the `.container-fluid` class, you can add `p-0` to the class in your HTML

```css
:root {
    --DarkerGray: #1b1d1d;
    --Gray: #3F4545;
    --MediumGray: #464a4a;
    --DarkBlue: #123B79;
    --LightBlue: #18A5A7;
    --LightGray: #D9D9D9;
    --LighterGray: #eceaea;
    --White: white;
    --OrangeSelect: rgb(255, 166, 0);
}
html, body {
    user-select: none;
}
.navbar {
    background-color: var(--DarkBlue);
}

.nav-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 550;

}
.dropdown-item {
    cursor: pointer;

    font-weight: 550;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: var(--OrangeSelect);
}


#containerIMG {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>  
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      CARDÁPIO
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> PRATOS </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> LANCHES </a>   
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> SOPAS </a>     
                  </li>
                   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      BEBIDAS
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> ÁGUAS </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> SUCOS </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> REFRIGERANTES </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> CERVEJAS </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> VINHOS </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> APERITIVOS </a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> DRINKS </a>    
                  </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white">RESERVAR MESA <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white"> PESQUISAR </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white"> MINHA CONTA </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white"> MEUS PEDIDOS</a>
              </li>
            </ul>   
          </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container-fluid p-0 bg-dark">
        <img src="https://t.ctcdn.com.br/essK16aBUDd_65hp5umT3aMn_i8=/400x400/smart/filters:format(webp)/i606944.png" id="containerIMG">
      </div
      </body>
```